# Is there any way to set a Type's GUID at runtime?

Tags: com, guid, ocx

How can I set a type's Guid dynamically?

Silly question, but I have an interface that is the exact same across several third-party COM Objects, but has a different GUID in each.

I have a C# interface that looks like so.

```
[Guid("1F13D3D8-3071-4125-8011-900D2EAC9A7F")]
[InterfaceType(2)]
[TypeLibType(4240)]
public interface UICtrl
{
  //stuff
}
```

I want to be able to change the GUID dynamically at run time depending on which COM object the user chooses to load. I can't change the meta data, and Type.Guid has no set property. Any ideas?

I can't use Remit.Emit because the calling assembly doesn't use it. I'm really stuck!

Comment: How are you using the interface?

Comment: @SLaks `(IConnectionPointContainer icpc = (IConnectionPointContainer)this.ocx; System.Guid g = typeof(UICtrl).GUID; icpc.FindConnectionPoint(ref g, out icp); icp.Advise(eventMulticaster, out mCookie);` That's why the interface GUID needs to be the same as the one in the COM object –

Comment: Sorry... I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use mini-markdown, despite the instructions at the bottom, and google is no help

Comment: Wrap it in ` characters.  I edited it.

Comment: Thanks! I swear I tried that! Noobs.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up fixing this by using a part of @SLaks's answer and my own. Basically I took my parent interface and generated a child interface from it which had the GUID I wanted.

```
AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("MulticasterAssembly");
            AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("MulticasterModule");
            TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("MainOCXMultiCaster", TypeAttributes.Public);
            tb.SetParent(typeof(AxUICtrlEventMulticaster));

            ConstructorInfo cInfo = typeof(GuidAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[] {typeof(string)});
            CustomAttributeBuilder cab = new CustomAttributeBuilder(cInfo, new object[] { mOCXType.GUID.ToString() });
            tb.SetCustomAttribute(cab);

            ConstructorBuilder cb = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

            Type childEventMulticaster = tb.CreateType();                

            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(childEventMulticaster);
            childEventMulticaster.InvokeMember("host", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, o, new object[] { this });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making three empty `[Guid]`'d interfaces which inherit a base interface with all of the members.

Comment: I think I understand. So it would be `[InterfaceType(2)]
[TypeLibType(4240)]
public interface UICtrl
{
  //stuff
}

[Guid("1F13D3D8-3071-4125-8011-900D2EAC9A7F")]
public interface UICtrlSpec1 : UICtrl {}
[Guid("Another GUID")]
public interface UICtrlSpec2 : UICtrl {}
[Guid("Still another GUID")]
public interface UICtrlSpec3 : UICtrl {}`

Comment: See? Totally wrapped it like you said. No dice. And how the heck do I make line breaks? I know it's the end of the day, but am I really that dense?

Comment: Unfortunately, newlines are not supported in comments.

Comment: To answer your question, Yes.  I'm not sure whether it will work, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The library in question provides a method that gives me the CLSID, and I'd like to continue to use that. With your suggestion, I'd have to hardcode them anyways (though, granted, I could load more of them).  Still hoping for a solution!